# How to use systemd timer to download and execute remote bash script?

Tags: bash, timer, systemd

I want to create a service called anything.service that downloads and executes a remote script ever 10 seconds I can create the timer but the service isn't executing the script.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

I'm looking for it to contain something along the lines of:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash "wget -O- http://server.com/script.sh | sh"
```

I can run this script by calling it with

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /etc/systemd/system/.script
```

But I'm looking for a way to run the line within the anything.service file.

Comment: You probably want to use the `cron` task scheduler that sound more appropriate to run commands at interval.

Comment: are you trying to make this an alias?

Comment: Also running a script as directly downloaded from http/s is security risk. At least add some integrity check before running the script: `[[ "$(wget -qO- http://server.com/script.sh | md5sum)" == "6e6180d7d8669c4977ff5df55bca5783  -" ]] && wget -qO- http://server.com/script.sh | sh` replace the md5 with that of the shell script and it will not execute if it does not match.

Comment: I think the reason OP wants to execute a remote script is that it needs to get the newest version before running it. Adding a security check is a very good advice however that defeats the purpose of downloading it first as any update will dissatisfy the md5 check. On the other hand if the script doesn't get updated often I do not see the need to download it every single time before running it.